# Visual basic sets the property which was given as an argument

Tags: vb.net

I have a very puzzling situation that i have discovered and i hope someone with deeper knowledge of VB.NET can help me. I have a method which looks like this

```
Public Function DoSomeWork(ByRef argument) As Boolean
    ...
    Return true
End Function
```

I call this method the following way

```
DoSomeWork(SomeObject.IntegerProperty)
```

My question is why does Visual Basic try to assign value to the SomeObject.IntegerProperty when "Return True" is called. Property is assiged with the same value it had earlier. Just to kae it clear i am not changing argument in any way i just take its value and assign it to some other property of totally unrelated object.

Comment: Why do you need `ByRef`, why don't you specify the type of `argument` which makes it an object implicitly? Why do you expect that  `SomeObject.IntegerProperty` gets a different value?

Comment: @TimSchmelter `argument` has no type by mistake. It is supposed to be an integer value. And as an answer to your second question i do not expect it to get a different value, this is something that VB does and i want to know why does this happen

Comment: Without showing the code of the `DoSomeWork` method, nobody will ever know what's going on. To help you, you have to show your code. Otherwise, your issue can't be reproduced.

Comment: @Tusker: the method does not change it unless you don't do: `argument = 101`

Answer (score 1):

This may be me misunderstanding the question, but it sounds like you're saying that your application sets the value of `SomeObject.IntegerProperty`. I'm not sure how you know this, but given that you're saying that `DoSomeWork` shouldn't alter `SomeObject.IntegerProperty`, the simple answer is to replace `ByRef` with `ByVal`. This will force the function to treat `IntegerProperty` as Read-only.